# Initialize a hash in the inject method to prevent a value being nil

Tags: ruby

I am trying to compile all the values for a given hash key in a list of hashes. I have the following which works.

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}].inject({}) do |hash, item|
    item.each do |key, value|
        hash[key] = [] if hash[key].nil?
        hash[key] << value
    end
    hash
end
```

Here is the result which is great:

```
{:a=>[1, 4, 7], :b=>[2, 5, 8], :c=>[3, 6, 9]}
```

My question: is there a more elegant way to initializing the hash so I don't need to check for the nil case in the following line?

```
hash[key] = [] if hash[key].nil?
```

I have tried `Hash.new(0)` as the default for the `inject` method but it doesn't work. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Don't forget `hash[key] ||= [ ]` is usually more than adequate and a whole lot less verbose.

Comment: What should be the output for `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}]` ?

Comment: It should just be: `{:a=>[1], :b=>[2]}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Solutions

You can use `each_with_object` :

```
array = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}]

empty_hash = Hash.new{ |h, k| h[k] = [] }
hash = array.each_with_object(empty_hash) do |small_hash, hash|
  small_hash.each do |k, v|
    hash[k] << v
  end
end

p hash
#=> {:a=>[1, 4, 7], :b=>[2, 5, 8], :c=>[3, 6, 9]}
```

A shorter, but more unusual version is here :

```
hash = array.each_with_object(Hash.new{ [] }) do |small_hash, hash|
  small_hash.each {|k, v| hash[k] <<= v }
end

p hash
#=> {:a=>[1, 4, 7], :b=>[2, 5, 8], :c=>[3, 6, 9]}
```

Both return `{:a=>[1], :b=>[2]}` for `[{a: 1}, {b: 2}]`, as the OP specified.

## <<= ?

`hash[k] <<= v` is a weird (and probably inefficient) trick. It is equivalent to :

```
hash[k] = (hash[k] << v)
```

The assignment is needed because the hash default hasn't been properly initialized, and a new array is being generated for every hash lookup, without being saved as a value :

```
h = Hash.new{ [] }
p h[:a] << 1
#=> [1]
p h[:a]
#=> []
p h[:a] <<= 1
#=> [1]
p h[:a]
#=> [1]
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you briefly explain or point me to documentation on the `<<=` part of the code?

Comment: I tried to explain it. If you don't want to confuse your colleagues or your future self, don't use it ;)

Comment: `<<=` is not too inefficient, it uses an additional `opt_aset` bytecode but otherwise creates just as many arrays as the other solution. Both solution create a new array on the first lookup of a key only.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do `Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }` to make values empty arrays by default.

Comment: Instead of `reduce` with `tap` inside, try `each_with_object`. Less mess. This will work, though.

Comment: ..And with `each_with_object` you don't need `tap`.

Comment: I deleted some parts of my answer, thus these comments don't make much sense.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to use [Enumerable#flat_map](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map), [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) and [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) (and a couple of more familiar methods).

```
arr = [{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': nil, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}]

arr.flat_map(&:to_a).group_by(&:first).each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),h|
  h[k] = v.map(&:last).compact }
  #=> {:a=>[1, 4, 7], :b=>[2, 8], :c=>[3, 6, 9]}
```

The steps are as follows. (The gory details are for the benefit--I hope--of newish Ruby users.)

```
a = arr.flat_map(&:to_a)
  #=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 3], [:a, 4], [:b, nil], [:c, 6], [:a, 7], [:b, 8], [:c, 9]] 

b = a.group_by(&:first)
  #=> {:a=>[[:a, 1], [:a, 4], [:a, 7]],
  #    :b=>[[:b, 2], [:b, nil], [:b, 8]],
  #    :c=>[[:c, 3], [:c, 6], [:c, nil]]} 

e = b.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: {:a=>[[:a, 1], [:a, 4], [:a, 7]], :b=>[[:b, 2], [:b, nil],
  #     [:b, 8]], :c=>[[:c, 3], [:c, 6], [:c, 9]]}:each_with_object({})>
```

The first value of the enumerator is generated and passed to the block, and the block variables are assigned, using *parallel assignment* (sometimes called *multiple assignment*).

```
(k,v),h = e.next
  #=> [[:a, [[:a, 1], [:a, 4], [:a, 7]]], {}] 
k #=> :a 
v #=> [[:a, 1], [:a, 4], [:a, 7]] 
h #=> {}
```

The block calculation is now performed.

```
c = v.map(&:last)
  #=> [1, 4, 7] 
d = c.compact
  #=> [1, 4, 7] 
h[k] = d
  #=> [1, 4, 7]
```

Now the second element of `e` is generated and passed to the block, together with the updated value of `h`, the block variables are assigned values and the block calculation is performed.

```
(k,v),h = e.next
  #=> [[:b, [[:b, 2], [:b, nil], [:b, 8]]], {:a=>[1, 4, 7]}] 
k #=> :b 
v #=> [[:b, 2], [:b, nil], [:b, 8]] 
h #=> {:a=>[1, 4, 7]} 
c = v.map(&:last)
  #=> [2, nil, 8] 
d = c.compact
  #=> [2, 8]
```

Note the `nil` value was removed in the previous step.

```
h[k] = d
  #=> [2, 8]
```

The third and last element is then generated by the enumerator and passed to the block.

```
(k,v),h = e.next
  #=> [[:c, [[:c, 3], [:c, 6], [:c, 9]]], {:a=>[1, 4, 7], :b=>[2, 8]}] 
k #=> :c 
v #=> [[:c, 3], [:c, 6], [:c, 9]] 
h #=> {:a=>[1, 4, 7], :b=>[2, 8]} 
c = v.map(&:last)
  #=> [3, 6, 9] 
d = c.compact
  #=> [3, 6, 9] 
d #=> [3, 6, 9] 
h[k] = d

h #=> {:a=>[1, 4, 7], :b=>[2, 8], :c=>[3, 6, 9]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also combine `inject` with `merge` like this:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6}, {'a': 7, 'b': 8, 'c': 9}].inject do |result, hash|
    result.merge(hash) { |_, first, second| [first, second].flatten }
end # => {:a=>[1, 4, 7], :b=>[2, 5, 8], :c=>[3, 6, 9]}
```

Comment: You could just write `[first,second].flatten`, couldn't you? Note that if a key only appears in one hash, your merge block won't get called, and the value won't be put in an Array. I don't know what the OP wants in this case.